# can't access www.livesite.com/admin

Tags: files

I have just transferred my local server to a live site. I am able to log in as an administrator, but I am not able to access my administrator tools. The page directs me to a blank page. Initially I was able to change the site's theme, through the admin tools, but now I can't even do that. I am not sure what am I doing wrong, or if there is something that I have to change in the settings.php file etc?

Btw, the site update was using ftp only.

Comment: Chech out http://drupal.org/node/158043/

Answer (score 2):

A blank page often indicates a PHP Error. Is there an error in the PHP error logs you can reference?

Also, when uploading via FTP, you want to be sure that you properly transferred your .htaccess file which, on some Operating Systems, will be hidden on your local filesystem.

Comment: I checked the .htcaccess files, they seem to be present in certain folders. Should it be present in all folders?

Comment: Which folders? I would assume your sites/default/files path and probably the document root. Do you have access to the watchdog to check for possible PHP errors?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are getting a memory_limit error for admin pages. Usual admin pages will take more memory. Please check the error log  and increase the memory_limit.

Comment: how do you increase memory_limit?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/207036  I followed this, and now my site won't even show up. www.asblab2012.mie.utoronto.ca

Comment: Your problem still exist or resolved?Have yuou checked your error log?

Answer (score 0):

Look in settings.php and change domains path, from your local to live domain.

Comment: I modified $base_url: asblab.mie.utoronto.ca  . It is weird, because i am able to access the admin/build/blocks, but others I cant access. Is it possible that my theme is protected or something?  Thanks.

Comment: is the admin theme on the first box installed on the second?

Comment: It can be a memory issue as John said. *Only way to find out is looking into your log files.*

Comment: I am really sorry guys, was able to come online today only. This is the dummy site www.asblab2012.mie.utoronto.ca , you can see the error messages. So this is what happened, I changed the theme to blue marine, and then I was unable to access the site as an admin again. This is a dummy site that has been rehosted again after I failed to access my original page.  The problem is I am not very familiar with log files, someone mentioned me to look in to /var/log/httpd/  error_log file.And I can't find it:/ .

Comment: I check my error_log file, this is one of the errors PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function json_decode() in /asblab/WWW/site2012/sites/all/themes/ninesixtyrobots/template.php on line 64 . If this error looks familiar let me know of any suggestions that you may all have :).

Comment: I just had to update the json_decode in server, which the server guy did. And also never change the .sql file manually because drupal has a weird way of reading sql file.